# An empty array is returned when using useState in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
function Search(){
    const [title, setTitle]=useState('');
    const [book, setBook]=useState([]);
    
    const onChange=(e)=> setTitle(e.target.value);

    const headers= {};
    const getBookList= async ()=>{
        try{
            const response=await axios.get(`https://dapi.kakao.com/v3/search/book?target=title&query=${title}`, {headers});
            setBook(response.data.documents);
            console.log(response.data.documents);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        getBookList();
        console.log(book);
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={title} onChange={onChange}></input>
            <button onClick={getBookList}>push</button>
            <div>{book[0]}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

`response.data.documents` holds data like photos:

[image]

However, the variable called book does not contain anything. `book[0]` outputs nothing. How can we process this data?

Comment: `book[0]` is undefined the _first_ time the component renders, because you set the default state to be `[]`. You also won't see anything when you `console.log(book)` because that hasn't been reassigned at that point.

Comment: Thank you ! To use the book variable, I have to wait for it to be assigned a value before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise has not been fulfilled yet when you are logging it. try like this

```
// two useeffect hooks, one for logging, other for populating
useEffect(()=>{
        getBookList();
},[]);

useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(book);
},[book]);
```

the whole component might look like this

```
function Search(){
  const [title, setTitle]=useState('');
  const [book, setBook]=useState([]);
  
  const onChange=(e)=> setTitle(e.target.value);

  const headers= {};
  const getBookList= ()=>{
    axios.get(`https://dapi.kakao.com/v3/search/book?target=title&query=${title}`, {headers}).then(res => {
      setBook(res.data.documents)
    })
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    getBookList()
  },[]);

  return (
      <div>
          <input value={title} onChange={onChange}></input>
          <button onClick={getBookList}>push</button>
          <div>{book.length > 0 ? JSON.stringify(book[0]) : ""}</div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Note: `{book.length > 0 ? book[0] : ""}` is for checking if the array has been populated, since at the moment the component loads, the request response hasnt arrived yet

Edit: do not render json in the dom, JSON.stringify(book[0]) is the correct way, if you want to see the json data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I tried adding this(<div>{book.length > 0 ? book[0] : ""}</div> ) content, but I got an error. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @sojinLee, i assume its because you are trying to render JSON to the dom, just add `JSON.stringify(book[0])`